# Finding continuous absentees in employee attendance register

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Attendance register have the following columns:

```
ID          Numeric Auto Increment  
Employee    ID Int  
Attendance  Bit
```

I need to find

1. how many employees has taken 'n' or more days leave continuously.
2. exactly n days leave before and after a working day. e.g.: two days before and two days after a working day
   where 'n' is the input parameter.

[image]

so far i've done simple queries. But searching for a continuously appearing value is something new to me.   can some body help where to start with..

Comment: Where are dates in your register? Also if you want to be helped provide enough sample data in tabular form and desired output based on that data.

Comment: We'll need some date field before we can help much further.

Comment: @peterm there are no date fields. One row will be entered for each day.

Comment: @Matt I ve posted the table data..

Comment: I would suggest extracting the rows for a specific EmployeeID. Also, it is assumed that for every employee and every day there is a row available?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers yes, for every employee attendance one new row will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write it in a query, but the algorithm would be something like:

Create for each employee an absense list, in the form:
[1, 3, 2, 2] where each element means the number of consecutive absense days after a consecutive number of working days. In this case e.g.

```
[False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
 <-1--> Work days   <---------3------->  Work days   <----2----->  Work  <----2----->
```

Now requirement (1) can be implemented by finding a number in the array that is >= n

Requirement (2) can be checked by finding two consecutive numbers in the array with value n.
(This solution is not correct, the number of working days should also be stored, possibly in a same length array, but I leave this to the user).

Comment: Requirement (2) seems to imply that there must be exactly one working day between the leaves, meaning it would not be enough to list the absence periods only. I might be reading too much into it, though.

Comment: Yes you are right ... in that case the working days should also be saved.